# System error 126 when connecting mysql C++ connector built with VC++ 2013

Tags: mysql, odbc, driver

Getting "system error 126" when doing "Test" connection from windows ODBC manager.

1. mysql server 5.7 installed
2. mysql C++ connector code cloned from github (checkout to 5.3 branch).
3. MDAC and CMAKE latest version installed.
4. Created VC++ project/solution by executing below commands.

   ```
   c:\mysql-connector-odbc>set MYSQL_DIR=c:\mysql-5.7.25-win32
   c:\mysql-connector-odbc>cmake -G "Visual Studio 12 2013" .
   ```
5. in Visual studio 2015 version 14, built solution file. (using Debug Mode)
6. Copied all the DLL (`myodbc5a.dll` for ANSI, `myodbc5w.dll` for UNICODE and `myodbc5S.dll` for setup) and corresponding LIB files to system folder `C:\windows\system32`.
7. Created Unicode and Ansi Drivers. Verified that drivers are installed in system registry.

   `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ODBC Drivers]`

   ```
   myodbc-installer.exe -d -a -n "MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver" -t "DRIVER=C:\mysql-connector-odbc\lib\Debug\myodbc5w.dll;SETUP=C:\mysql-connector-odbc\lib\Debug\myodbc5S.dll"

   myodbc-installer.exe -d -a -n "MySQL ODBC 5.3 Ansi Driver" -t "DRIVER=C:\mysql-connector-odbc\lib\Debug\myodbc5a.dll;SETUP=C:\mysql-connector-odbc\lib\Debug\myodbc5S.dll"
   ```
8. Here I gave the driver's build path. In this case I am able to get ODBC configuration screen. If I create driver without specifying driver path (refers to `c:\windows\system32`), I am getting system error 126 when add/configure DSN in ODBC manager.

   ```
   myodbc-installer.exe -d -a -n "MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver" -t "DRIVER=myodbc5w.dll;SETUP=myodbc5S.dll"
   myodbc-installer.exe -d -a -n "MySQL ODBC 5.3 Ansi Driver" -t "DRIVER=myodbc5a.dll;SETUP=myodbc5S.dll"
   ```
9. Created system DSN (`testansi` and `testunicode`) using ODBC Data source Administrator (32 bit) after creating driver with point 7.

When I do Test connection, following error message in windows dialogue appears.

> The specified driver could not be loaded due to system error 126. The specified module could not be found.
>
> (MYSQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver, c:\mysql-connector-odbc\lib\release\myodbc5a.dll)

Test connection fails. It should pass.

Comment: Looks like you're picking the wrong driver from the Administrator's list, as you've built the Unicode driver, but it's trying to load the ANSI driver. Might be some Registry corruption in there, among other possibilities. Also, double-check your bitness -- as the [32-bit ODBC Admin is counterintuitively located](http://wikis.openlinksw.com/UdaWikiWeb/Win32vs64OdbcAdmin).

Comment: I verified with both ANSI and UNICODE drivers. Also I checked with registry in ODBC 32 bit location [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ODBC Drivers]. Drivers are installed. When I built mysql gitgub source code(mysql ODBC connector) using VC++, I got three DLL and their respective libraries. myodbc5a.dll for Ansi, myodbc5w.dll for unicode and myodbc5S.dll for setup. I copied these DLL and LIB files to system folder.(c:\windows\system32). I created ANSI and UNICODE drivers. In both the the drivers having same issue.

Comment: Note that on 64-bit Windows, `c:\windows\system32` contains *64-bit* libraries.  32-bit libraries should be placed in `c:\windows\SysWOW64`. If you move the MyODBC DLLs and LIBs from `system32` to `SysWOW64`, your errors may be resolved. If not... *something* is pointing to `c:\mysql-connector-odbc\lib\release\myodbc5a.dll` but you've put this at `c:\windows\system32\myodbc5a.dll`. A Windows shortcut pointing from the former to the latter *may* then resolve the error.

Comment: Thank you very much for replying. I have tried after copying my 32 bit libraries to c:\windows\SysyWoW64 but no luck, same error. When I am registering my DLL, I am getting error "The module "myodbc5a.dll" failed to load. specified module could not be found".

Comment: getting following error from trace log ......    odbcad32        db0-1a94 EXIT  SQLGetDiagRecW  with return code 0 (SQL_SUCCESS)
  SQLSMALLINT                  2 <SQL_HANDLE_DBC>
  SQLHANDLE           0x046C9050
  SQLSMALLINT                  1 
  SQLWCHAR *          0x0099BBA4 [       5] "IM003"
  SQLINTEGER *        0x0099BB98 (160)
  SQLWCHAR *          0x06A8CE54 [     198] "Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error  126: The specified module could not be found. (MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver, C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL_Connector_ODBC\lib\myodbc5w.dll)."

Comment: These additional details would be better provided as edits to your question, for formatting among other things. It appears you're testing multiple things, as `myodbc5a.dll` is the missing file in one, and `myodbc5w.dll` in another. Please look to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for guidance on how to help us to help you...

Comment: I have tried different ways to make ANSI and UNICODE driver works. These are additional details I got during my try. To make my question specific, I have not given additional details.During building solution file in VC++ 2013, I am getting following warnings repeatedly.                                                       4>C:\mysql-connector-odbc\include\sys\m_string.h(173): warning C4273: 'strnlen' : inconsistent dll linkage
4>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\string.h(125) : see previous definition of 'strnlen'

Comment: Perhaps a silly question... Rather than building your own, can you use the [pre-built drivers, provided by the MySQL folks](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/)?

Comment: I need to modify source code so that I can connect to custom database. Anyway I am able to do this through PostgreSQL.